# Object allocated on stack or heap c++

Tags: c++

```
Dictionary::Dictionary() {
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("words");
    string wread;
    while(getline(infile,wread)){
        wordset.insert(wread);
        vector<string> st =Read::Trigrams(wread);
                //Word w(wread,st) stack försvinner när vi lämnar metoden.
        words[wread.length()].push_back(Word(wread,st)); //stack eller heap
    }
    infile.close();
}
```

This i a constructor for a class Dictionary. 
I want to create a word object and add it to vector.
Should i write 
words[wread.length()].push_back(Word(wread,st));
or 
Word w(wread,st);
words[wread.length()].push_back(w);
w will be allocated on the stack and it will be removed when we leave the constructor.

Comment: It makes no difference, they are both allocated on the stack.

Comment: Actually you should use `emplace_back` for possible performance improvement and clarity.

Comment: @HansPassant the standard does not specify that actually, but practically you are correct. Objects with an _automatic_ storage duration are almost always allocated on the stack. However an implementation may choose to allocate on the heap insofar as the lifetime is still automatic.

Comment: @Mgetz "Objects with an automatic storage duration are _almost always_ allocated on the stack" - Uhhh no. What about all those value objects declared in classes?

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 the first form `push_back(Word());` is going to be more efficient, iff `Word` has a move constructor. The second form will make a copy regardless.

Functionality wise, both are equivalent. The second pollutes the scope, the first doesn't. The first is more likely to be optimized efficiently, the second isn't.

Unless restricted by backward compatibility you should use `vector::emplace_back` and either pass a value of `T` or the parameters of one of its constructors.

Comment: but if u do push on a obj created on stack what will happen when when constructor finishes?

Comment: @user2975699: It's copied into the container. The local instance will be destroyed when the constructor completes, but the copy in the container will be safe.

Comment: @user2975699 When you `push_back` an object, a copy is made and saved in the vector. The value that has been copied from is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the forms you mentioned will allocate on the heap.  To allocate on the heap you will *generally* use the `new` keyword

```
new Word()
```

There are other ways to allocate on the heap including `std::make_shared`. But none are used in your sample.  Using simply `Word()` will allocate on the stack

Comment: You can also allocate objects on the heap by calling `std::make_shared` instead of `new`.

Answer (score 1):

The "proper" way to do this is to use `emplace_back`, which will construct the Word in-place, removing even the move.

Note that `emplace_back` takes the same arguments as the object's constructor.

Comment: You should probably mention that this is a C++11 feature.